# getInvoices method failing

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We have been using the getInvoices to extract costs for a specific time period. Today we tried this command.

```
curl -k -n "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/286900/getInvoices?objectMask=mask%5Bid,closedDate,createDate,typeCode,invoiceTotalAmount,invoiceTotalOneTimeAmount,invoiceTotalRecurringAmount,invoiceTopLevelItems%5Bid,description,hostName,domainName,totalRecurringAmount,totalOneTimeAmount,parentId,categoryCode,billingItemId,billingItem%5Bid,orderItem%5Bid,order%5Bid,userRecord%5Bid,username,firstName,lastName%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D%5D&objectFilter=%7B%22invoices%22:%7B%22createDate%22:%7B%22operation%22:%20%22betweenDate%22,%22options%22:%20%5B%7B%22name%22:%20%22startDate%22,%20%22value%22:%20%5B%227/29/2016%200:0:0%22%5D%7D,%7B%22name%22:%20%22endDate%22,%20%22value%22:%20%5B%228/5/2916%2023:59:59%22%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D"
```

The return is "{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}"

I have no idea what this error means.  The date span for the invoices is from 7/29/2016 to 8/5/2016.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not able to reproduce the problem, but maybe the cause is related a lot information in the response. Please try again the request by adding `Result limits`.

These articles can help you:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/How-Solve-Error-fetching-http-headers
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST

### Update:

After executing some tests more, an error message displays when trying to execute [SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices)

> {   "error": "Allowed memory size of 402653184 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 4 bytes)",   "code": "Client" }

I assume that is a huge number of data to break the execution and the problem may be the memory usage limit.

In that case `result limits` can help us, this is a basic example:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?resultLimit=0,10

Method: GET
```

Comment: Well, I have bad news.  I am still getting the error "{"error":"Internal Error","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}".  I looked at the documentation for SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices and it doesn't support resultLimits. Where do i go from here? Did you actually run the URL against my account?

Comment: I executed the request using your account but it takes a lot of minutes before retrieving the data. The result limits works for `SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices`. Please see my update in the answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Wow, I just noticed the end date was 8/5/2916.  Changed it to 8/5/2016 and all is well.   Thanks for your help.  I did implement resultLimit anyway.  :-)